# How to access specific parts of JSON for API call - Python

Tags: python, json, api

I want to access 'employmentName' and 'jobTile' values.
But I keep on getting this error - KeyError: 'jobTitle' and KeyError: 'employmentName'

Here is my code below, please note I am not sharing the api URL on this question but it is present and working in the code.

```
api_three_url = "https://xxxx"
json_data_three = requests.get(api_three_url, headers=my_headers).json()
#print(json_data_three) #this prints the whole json data (working!)

print("So you have previously worked in", json_data_three['employmentName'],"as a", json_data_three['jobTitle'])
```

This is what the JSON looks like in python dict:

```py
{
    'hasAddedValue': False,
    'employments': [{
        'id': 527,
        'employmentName': 'Sallys hair',
        'jobTitle': 'Stylists',
        'jobStartDate': '2019-03',
        'jobEndDate': '2020-04',
        'jobType': 'PAID',
        'status': True,
        'isJobCurrent': False
    }]
}
```

Please guide me to where I am going wrong.

Many thanks :)

Comment: `json_data_three["employments"][0]["employmentName"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `employmentName` and `jobType` fields are not at the top level in your JSON, hence Python is giving you `KeyError`. They are actually in one of the objects inside `employments`.

So if you want to obtain those fields from the first object inside `employments`, it would be:

```py
json_data_three['employments'][0]['employmentName']
```

Comment: Yes I understand, all working now many thanks!